# Use Regular Expressions to find a date in a String

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am trying to use regular Expressions to extract the dates from a string using VBA in Excel.

The string is:

```
Previous Month: 9/1/2015 - 9/30/2015
```

Or it can be :

```
Custom: 9/1/2015 - 9/30/2015
```

Do you have any idea how can I achieve that? I have never used Regular Expressions before.

Comment: try this regex :) : [**Regex101 Example**](https://regex101.com/r/oI1oO6/1)

Answer (score 2):

RegEx is a poor choice for dates. You could look for `:` and examine the remaining tokens:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim result() As Variant

    result = GetDates("Previous Month: 9/1/2015 - 9/30/2015")

    If UBound(result) Then
        Debug.Print result(0)
        Debug.Print result(1)
    End If
End Sub

Function GetDates(str As String) As Variant()
    Dim tokens() As String
    tokens = Split(Mid$(str, InStr(str & ": ", ":")), " ")

    If (UBound(tokens) = 3) Then
        If IsDate(tokens(1)) And IsDate(tokens(3)) Then
            GetDates = Array(CDate(tokens(1)), CDate(tokens(3)))
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    ReDim GetDates(0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
([1-9]|1[012])[/]([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])[/](19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

search a commandtext string for dates and then replace them with a new date

```
dim regex as object
 Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
 regex.Pattern = "\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{2,4}"
 regex.Global = True
 Set regexMatches = regex.Execute(CommandText)
 for i=0 to regexMatches.Count()
        date1 = regexMatches(i)
 next
```